# Codeigniter form_validation: The view of form repeat when I submit it with errors

Tags: codeigniter

Hello I'm using **codeigniter**.I have some problem with my form when i submit it with errors. the probem is that the form repeat in the view like this:
[image screenshot of form.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojEOF.png)

this is my controller:

```
public function registerform()
{
    $this->layout->view('editeur/editeur_inscription');
}
public function register()
{
    $this->_register_rules();
    if($this->form_validation->run()) {
        //tratement
    } else {
        $this->registerform();
    }
}
```

Comment: can u show the url given to form action

Comment: <form method="post" action ="<?php echo site_url(array('editeur','register')); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 0):

please change the code like this and try it

```
public function registerform()
{
   $config = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'heading',
                'label' => 'Heading',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'description',
                'label' => 'Description',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ));
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
   if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
    $this->register();
   } else {
    $this->load->view('editeur/editeur_inscription');
  }
}

public function register()
{

  //do after success validation
}
```

in form

```
<form method="post" action ="<?php echo site_url(array('editeur','registerform')); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: That for your answer but there is no change.

Comment: Good. now it run.thank you Shibon for your help.you're a good developper